# Does parallelizability by a frame of commuting vector fields imply those fields are coordinate vector fields of a global chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a parallelizable manifold, is the following true?

> If $(X_i)$ is a (global) frame of $M$ and $[X_i,X_j]=0$ for all $i,j$, then there is a global chart for which $X_i=\partial_i$.

Comment: If there is a global chart, $M = \mathbb{R}^n$. Even then it is not true, take $X_i = 2\partial_i$.

Comment: @MichaelA: But you can *choose* your global chart so that his statement is true.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The circle $\Bbb S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ is parallelizable by the frame containing the standard vector field, $X_{(x, y)} := -y \partial_x + x \partial_y$, but (because it is compact) it admits no global chart at all.

The vector field $X$ is sometimes abusively denoted $\partial_{\theta}$, but this question demonstrates how this notation can be misleading.

Comment: Do we have $[X_i,X_j]=0$ for the frame you are taking on the circle?

Comment: Yes, that's trivially true: The only commutator is $[X, X]$, but this is zero for any vector field $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I have therefore a follow-up question : can we always find a global frame $(X_i)$ on a parallelizable manifold satisfying $[X_i,X_j]=0$?

Comment: I don't think so (I expect this cannot be done for $\Bbb S^3$ for example) but I don't immediately see how to show that.

Comment: (And you're welcome.)

Comment: Okay, thank you I'm going to ask a question on this then.

Comment: When you do, you should link to this question.

Comment: The circle is covered by $\mathbf{R}$. Is there an example where such a manifold with commuting fields cannot be covered by $\mathbf{R}^n$ in a way that the fields be the images of the "coordinate fields"?

Comment: @Alexey At least not in the compact case: If the fields all commute, their flows definesan action of $\Bbb R^n$ on $M$ with discrete kernel $\Gamma$, so $\Bbb R^n \mapsto \Bbb R^n/\Gamma \cong M$ is a covering map. Moreover, $\Gamma$ must be a lattice, so $M$ must be a torus.